# PostgreSQL Syntax error in PGAdmin

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am new to PostgreSQL and am using the query tool in PGAdmin. I'm trying to run pgsql queries that use variables, but I can't seem to get the syntax right.

Here's a sample query that gives a syntax error:

```
DECLARE
  num INTEGER;

BEGIN

  num := 3;
  PRINT num;

END;
```

---

Update:
Ok, let me try and explain. I come from a SQL server background. In the management studio, I can open a query window and play with (T)-SQL queries.

For example, I can write something like this:

```
DECLARE @num INT
SET @num = 3
SELECT @num
```

I know this is a dumb example, but I'm just trying to declare a variable and do something with it. I'm trying to familiarise myself with PL/PGSQL.

---

Update, again:
It's me again. I'm trying the script below and get a "[ERROR    ] 7.0-2: syntax error, unexpected character". Is this meant to work in PGAdmin?

```
DECLARE
  num INTEGER;

BEGIN

  num := 3;
  RAISE NOTICE '%', num;

END;
```

Comment: Coming from the MSSQL/TSQL world as well I ran into the same issue. I'm very surprised that you can't just write and run one-off PL/PGSQL scripts in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the do statement. For example:

```
do $$
declare 
  num integer := 10;
begin

    RAISE INFO 'VARIABLE: %', num;

end;
$$language plpgsql;
```

When you use pgadmin you have to use the button EXECUTE QUERY instead of
Execute pdScript, as it is explained here:

http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/PgAmin3-Anonymous-code-block-can-t-be-executed-by-pressing-quot-Execute-PG-script-quot-button-td5771073.html

The documentation for do statements is here:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-do.html

Answer (score 5):

Just to rephrase and "concretize" what others say:
There are no **inline procedures** in PostgreSQL. There is also **no PRINT statement**. You have to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test() RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
  num INTEGER;

BEGIN

  num := 3;
  RAISE NOTICE '%', num;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT test();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to print out `num` (say, for debugging), you could try:

```
RAISE NOTICE '%', num;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html

`PRINT` doesn't mean anything in PL/pgSQL.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what you are trying to achieve. PostgreSQL doesn't support this kind of syntax. Similar keywords (except PRINT?!) are in PL/pgSQL which is procedural language for building FUNCTIONS, not for writing stand-alone SQL queries.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres doesn't support anything like that by itself ([yet](http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/release-8-5.html#AEN95772)). [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) (the official command line client) has some rudimentary scripting.

The best option for you is pgAdmin which already has [scripting](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.10/pgscript.html) built-in.