# Is it possible to write a PostgreSQL query that exports different tables by using a loop?

Tags: sql, postgresql, loops

I would like to export several tables, but each of them created under a different condition and with different file names. For example, it is possible to create a table under the condition that a certain id is equal to x and to export this table to a file called table_x.txt. This can be done by using the following (simple) query.

```
COPY(
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE table.id=x
)
TO '/home/table_x.txt'
;
```

However, instead of doing this about 100 times, I would like to generate a loop which performs this query for different values of x. Is this possible? I don't need to save the different tables in my database, I only want to export them to different text files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
DO $$
DECLARE r record;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN 
            SELECT id FROM id_list
  LOOP
    COPY(
      SELECT *
      FROM table
      WHERE table.id=r.id
    )
    TO '/home/table_'||r.id||'.txt';
  END LOOP;
END $$;
```

It is an anonymous PL/SQL function that will loop through `id` in `SELECT id FROM id_list` and execute `COPY` for every id.

Comment: Are you sure that's legal - an expression in `COPY` there, in PL/PgSQL? I was expecting to need `EXECUTE`.

Comment: @CraigRinger It indeed gives a syntax error at or near '||'. This query also gave me a syntax error at or near     DO, so I replaced this line by "CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test() RETURNS void AS $$" and set the language to plpgsql. I work in pgAdmin and used [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899123/postgresql-syntax-error-in-pgadmin) post. Is this correct?